# Listing the volumes on Solaris OS

Tags: solaris

I am new to solaris OS, and trying to write a script which collects volume data from solaris box.

We did a similar script for Linux, and we used "df -P" command to list the volumes, and select the entries that start with "/dev".

By default, in linux, i could see a volume "/dev/sda1".

when i run df command on solaris box(df -k),i could not see any entry similar to (/dev/*) in my output.

When i mounted a CD, i could see an entry in df output as below.

```
/dev/dsk/c1t1d0s2          57632       57632           0   100%    /media/VBOXADDITIONS_5.0.14_105127
```

So, in solaris, what is the pattern, i should look for to pick the volumes?
And, why am I not seeing at least one volume in the pattern /dev/
is it "/dev" or something else?

I am using solaris 11 image on oracle virtual box.

When i try "format" command, i could see 3 disks:

```
AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:
       0. c1d0 <VBOX HAR-8ea18e8b-2b2a0a5-0001-31.25GB>  testvolu
          /pci@0,0/pci-ide@1,1/ide@0/cmdk@0,0
       1. c2d0 <VBOX HAR-b4343b55-dbed77c-0001 cyl 1020 alt 2 hd 64 sec 32>
          /pci@0,0/pci-ide@1,1/ide@1/cmdk@0,0
       2. c3t0d0 <ATA-VBOX HARDDISK-1.0 cyl 1009 alt 2 hd 64 sec 32>
          /pci@0,0/pci8086,2829@d/disk@0,0
```

But, i dont see any partition in "df -k"

Also, i read here(https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/805-6331/6j5vgg680/index.html), that disk names should be in "/dev/dsk/*" format.

Answer (score 2):

Solaris 11 uses ZFS which has no one to one relationship between volumes (partitions) and file systems.

You can look at `zpool status` output to get the underlying devices.

```
$ zpool status
  pool: rpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME      STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    rpool     ONLINE       0     0     0
      c1t0d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Here, the whole `c1t0d0` disk is used, hence no `sx` or `px` suffix.

Comment: i read here(https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/805-6331/6j5vgg680/index.html), that disk names should be in "/dev/dsk/*" format. So, why don't i see any partitions even though "format" command is showing 3 disks?

Comment: Where don't you see partitions and why do you want partitions to appear in the first place?

Comment: i dont see the partitions under "df -k", i am coding for a monitoring product, where i need to show all the 'volume' related data from solaris server

Comment: You don't see partitions under `df -k` for the reason I already stated in my answer.

Comment: Well, as far as ZFS is concerned, you can use the one I already suggested in my reply, `zpool status`.